# Is it possible to call subclasses' methods on a superclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Animal is a superclass of Dog 
and Dog has a method called bark

```
public void bark()
{
    System.out.println("woof");
}
```

Consider the following:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
if (a instanceof Dog){
    a.bark();
}
```

What will happen?

1. the assignment isn't allowed
2. the call to bark is allowed and "woof" is printed at run time
3. the call to bark is allowed but nothing is printed
4. the call to bark causes a compile time error
5. the call to bark results in a run time error

I said 2 as we are checking if the object is a dog; as dog is the class with the bark method in it, if it is then we call it which will print out :s

Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: suggest changing the question here to "Do superclasses have the methods of their subclasses?" or similar.

Comment: The trick is that You are checking to make sure it's a dog, but the Compiler doesn't make the logical connection that a.bark will only be called if a is a Dog. You'd have to explicitly tell the compiler to treat a like a Dog for the purpose of the bark() call, like Simon622 said below.

Comment: Incidentally, this is why many people prefer "duck typing". In, say, Python, the equivalent code wouldn't even need to check if `a` was a Dog; as long as `a` had a `bark` method when that line was reached, it would work.

Comment: Lucky that was worth 1 mark only lol

god if the question had read "Do superclasses have the methods of their subclasses?" i would have got the mark :@ lol

anyway i can extend the questions on here so i can check some more

Comment: It has been suggested that the language be expanded to allow this inference. However, it is unclear how it would affect overloading, casting is nasty, and I don't think Alex likes the definite assignment/unassignment chapter as it is.

Comment: Re: duck typing--bad answer.  If an animal could make a noise, makeNoise() should be in the animal base class.  You should almost never have to use casting.  If only some animals can make noise, that should be a subclass from which dog extends (or the method should throw an exception or return null).  The upswing is that if you design your classes right, you very rarely need casting, so if you find duck typing really useful, check your design skills.

Comment: In Java, "duck typing" by casting is perhaps symptomatic of bad design (or at least of not really getting the language). Not in Python, where the whole point is that every method is its own little interface (and any combination of methods called by a given routine is implicitly an interface). Cats make noise but they don't bark, so if you have to define a "makeNoise" method in order to find out whether a given animal can bark, then check your own design...

Answer (score 33):

This won't compile since Animal does not have a method called bark.  Think of it this way, all dogs are animals, but not all animals are dogs.  All dogs bark, but not all animals bark.

Answer (score 27):

no - the answer is;

4) the call to bark causes a compile time error

the bark method isnt defined as a method on the assigned type Animal, which will therefore result in compile time issue; this could be solved by casting;

```
((Dog)a).bark();
```

Answer (score 12):

The key is in the following line:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Although a new instance of `Dog` was created, its reference is by `a` which is declared to be of the type `Animal`. Therefore, any references to `a` makes the `new Dog` be handled as an `Animal`.

Therefore, unless `Animal` has a `bark` method, the following line will cause a compiler error:

```
a.bark();
```

Even though `a` is tested to see if it is an instance of `Dog`, and `a instanceof Dog` will actually return `true`, the variable `a` is still of is of type `Animal`, so the block inside the `if` statement still handles `a` as an `Animal`.

This is a feature of [statically-typed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) where variables are assigned a type ahead of time, and checked at compile-time to see that the types match. If this code were performed on a [dynamically-typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing), where the types are checked at runtime, something like the following could be allowed:

```
var a = new Dog();
if (a instanceof Dog)
    a.bark();
```

`a.bark()` is guaranteed only to execute when the instance is a `Dog`, so the call to `bark` will always work. However, Java is a statically-typed language, so this type of code is not allowed.

Comment: +1 for adding the explanation re: statically- vs dynamically-typed languages.

Comment: What happens if both the classes have the bark() method, which one is executed.

Comment: @Rahul Kadukar:  If "**animal** is a superclass of **dog**", and both classes have the **bark()** method, then **bark()** is overridden to the **bark()** method in the subclass **dog**.  Thus, a.bark() will execute the **bark()** method in the **dog** class.

Answer (score 6):

In [Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651/) they use the very good analogy of a TV remote control for a *reference* and your TV as the *object* that the reference points to.  If your remote only has buttons (methods) for on, off, channel up and down, and volume up and down, it doesn't matter what cool features your TV has.  You can still only do those few basic things from your remote.  You can't mute your TV, for example, if your remote has no mute button.

The Animal reference only knows about Animal methods.  It doesn't matter what other methods the underlying object has, you can't access them from an Animal reference.

Answer (score 4):

It's 4.  You can't ask a generic Animal - which is what your code says a is - to bark.  Because you could just as easily have said

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

and the bark line doesn't have a way to know that you didn't.

Answer (score 4):

If the idea is to print the subclass method from superclass object, this will work:

Instead of `Animal a = new Dog();  if (a instanceof Dog){  a.bark();  }`
change to

```
Animal a = new Dog();

if (a instanceof Dog){ 
    Dog d = (Dog) a; 
    d.bark();
}
```

This casts the superclass back to subclass and prints it.
although its bad design, its one way to know which child class object its pointing to dynamically.

Comment: Or, if you must do something like this, you could do `if(a instanceof Dog) { ((Dog) a).bark(); }`

Answer (score 3):

In java(only language i know) you can create an empty method and call it in super class. Then you can override it in subclass to do whatever you want. This way the super class calls its subclass' method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Snake S = new Snake();
        Dog d = new Dog();
    }
}


class Animal{ //Super Class
    public Animal(){
        bark(); //calls bark when a new animal is created
    }
    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("this animal can't bark");
    }
}



class Dog extends Animal{ //Subclass 1
    @Override
    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}



class Snake extends Animal{//Subclass 2
    public void tss(){
    }
}
```

This code calls an object of Snake then calls an object of Dog. It writes this to console:

```
this animal can't bark
Woof
```

Snake doesn't have any bark method so super class' method is called. It writes the first line to the console. 
Dog has a bark method so super class calls it instead. It writes the second line to the console.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this is not a good design.

Just about any time you have code of this form:

```
if (x instanceof SomeClass)
{
   x.SomeMethod();
}
```

you are abusing the type system. This is not the way to use classes, it's not the way to write maintainable object oriented code. It's brittle. It's convoluted. It's bad.

You can create template methods in a base class, but they have to call methods that exist in the base class and are overridden in sub-classes.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I said 2 as we are checking if the object is a dog; as dog is the class with the bark method in it, if it is then we call it which will print out :s"*

Your rationale is correct, but that's not the way it works.

Java is an static typed language that means, the validity of the methods an object may respond to is verified at **compile time**.

You may think the check:

```
if( a instanceof Dog )
```

Would do, but actually it doesn't. What the compiler do is check against the "interface" of the declared type ( Animal in this case ). The "interface" is composed of the methods declared on the Animal class.

If the *bark()* method is not defined in the super class **Animal** the compiler says: "Hey, that won't work".

This is helpful, because "sometimes" we make typos while coding ( typing barck() instead for instance )

If the compiler doesn't not warn us about this, you would have to find it at "runtime" and not always with a clear message ( for instance javascript in IE says something like "unexpected object" )

Still, static typed language like java allow us to force the call. In this case it is using the "cast" operator ()

Like this

```
1. Animal a = new Dog();
2.  if (a instanceof Dog){
3.     Dog imADog = ( Dog ) a;
4.     imADog.bark();
5. }
```

In line 3 your are "casting" to a Dog type so the compiler may check if bark is a valid message.

This is an instruction to to compiler saying "Hey I'm the programmer here, I know what I'm doing".  And the compiler, checks, Ok, dog, can receive the message bark(), proceed. Yet, if in runtime the animal is not a dog, a runtime exception will raise.

The cast could also be abbreviated like:

```
if( a instanceof Dog ) {
   ((Dog)a).bark();  
}
```

That will run.

So, the correct answer is **4:** "*the call to bark causes a compile time error*"

I hope this helps.