# Changing parent object to child object

Tags: java, parent-child

I need a bit of help here. so i have this. I was basically wondering when you create an array of object of a parent class, then change that object to a child class, can I access the methods of that child class and if not why. thanks for any help.

```
public class Racer {

private String name;
private int position;

// Constructor
public Racer()
{}
public Racer(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    position = 0;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}


public int getPosition()
{
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int n)
{
    position = n;
}
public void setName(String n){
    this.name=n;
}
}
```

the child class

```
public class Spartiates extends Racer{

private int energy;

public Spartiates(){
    super();
}

public Spartiates(String name){
    setName(name);
    setPosition(20);
    energy=100;
}

public void setEnergy(int energy){
    this.energy=energy;
}

public int getEnergy(){
    return energy;
}
}
```

main class

```
 public class demo{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        Racer [] player = new player[3];
        for(int i=0; i<player.length; i++){
            player[i] = new Spartiates();
        }
        System.out.println(player[1].getEnergy());
  }
```

so here the problem the getEnergy method doesn't work so I was wondering why. If anybody can help it would be very much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discussed here:

[Is it possible to call subclasses' methods on a superclass object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898909/is-it-possible-to-call-subclasses-methods-on-a-superclass-object)

Along with all the reasons why doing something like this is probably never a good idea :).

You'll have to cast it to an instance of the subclass. If you plan on having a mixed array of object instances you'd need to first check the type:

```
System.out.println(((Racer)player[1]).getEnergy());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either define the function in the superclass or cast the object to the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend the array to hold ONLY elements of the subclass `Spartiates`, then declare it as such.

Otherwise, if it needs to hold objects of both type, there only way to do this is to check with `instanceof`.

```
if (player[1] instanceof Spartiates)
    System.out.println(((Spartiates)player[1]).getEnergy());
else
    // handle other types
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason energy is 0 is because you are calling your empty (no arg) constructor:

```
player[i] = new Spartiates();
```

which does not initialize the `energy` variable (so it will be 0 by default). You only set the variable to 100  in the constructor which takes in a `String`, namely here:

```
public Spartiates(String name){
    setName(name);
    setPosition(20);
    energy=100;
}
```

So either call that constructor in the for loop with some string as an argument, or call your `setEnergy()` setter with some value after creating the object with the empty constructor.

Also, this is wrong:

```
Racer [] player = new player[3];
```

It should read:

```
Racer [] player = new Racer[3];
```

or:

```
Racer [] player = new Spartiates[3];
```