# Saving a subclass as a superclass type and using its methods in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

In the code below, a subclass extends its superclass, and overrides its method, using it to call another method unique to the subclass, which uses a variable of the subclass.

The program then stores an instance of the subclass to a variable of type Superclass, and then calls its method. It then runs as if it is of type Subclass, calling the method and variable unique to the subclass. However, it is impossible to access these directly.

```
class Superclass {
    void go() {
        System.out.println(0);
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    void go() {
        run();
    }

    void run() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public class JavaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Superclass instance = new Subclass();

        instance.go();                 // outputs 1; it must have called run() and accessed i
        instance.run();                // causes compile-time error
        System.out.println(instance.i);// causes compile-time error
    }
}
```

Once the Subclass instance is saved as type Superclass, it still have access to all Subclass fields and methods. So why can't I access them directly?

Comment: Because the reference type is the superclass and there is no guarantee that the referenced object has this methods.

Comment: Indeed. Just because YOU know they're there, doesn't mean the computer can guarantee they will be. What you are trying to do is called [downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting), and generally speaking it's a bad, bad thing to do and likely means your design needs to be thought through more carefully. There are some situations where it is unavoidable, but those are few and far between (especially with proper Generics)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call subclasses' methods on a superclass object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898909/is-it-possible-to-call-subclasses-methods-on-a-superclass-object)

Comment: If you *know* that a reference typed Superclass is in fact a Subclass object, you can simply cast it to Subclass to reference the methods of Subclass.  There is nothing wrong with doing this (though sometimes a more careful design can avoid the need).

Comment: `((Subclass)instance).run();` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In case of variables and static methods, the method according to the type of reference is called, not according to the object being referred.

But in case of instance methods, the method is called according to the type of object being referred, not according to the type of reference

Comment: Except that the OP's problem is that the subclass method cannot be even referred to since the reference is declared to be of the superclass.