# Can a superclass have an instance variable of a subclass type?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For example,

```
public class Folder {
    // ...
    private List<Subfolder> subfolders;
}
```

and

```
public class Subfolder extends Folder {
    // ...
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, a `Subfolder` will inherit all the fields of the `Folder` superclass, including its `List<Subfolder>`. However, because the list is private to `Folder`, and as long as I don't write any accessor or mutator methods for the list, I can rest assured that a `Subfolder` will not be able to do anything with `Folder`'s list of subfolders. What I feel conflicted about is whether this is considered good design. If a `Subfolder` is unable to access the `Folder`'s list of subfolders, why inherit it at all?

Comment: For which reason would you want that kind of design. Couldn't you just have a List of Folders in the Folder class?

Answer (score 1):

A child class inherit the non-private fields from its parent. What you have there is a bad design because a parent class should not know about their child classes.

You have a high coupling which is bad because you are making Folder depend on its child.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion. However, in Herbert Schildt's _Java: A Beginner's Guide_, he says "even though a subclass includes all of the members of its superclass, it cannot access those members of the superclass that have been declared private." So, unless I'm not privy to some technicality, the child does inherit all fields, including private, it just cannot access them.

Answer (score 1):

- #### [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Programming_languages)

  One possiblity is an `abstract` `Folder`, it might delegate behavior that it does not implement to `SubFolder` instances. I *see* no requirement that `SubFolder` must be an instance of `Folder` vis-a-vis compiling `Folder`.
- #### Encapsulation

  A `private` field is not inherited because the field is not directly accesible (it is encapsulated). Mutability often requires synchronization amongst threads (or something like Copy-On-Write). Regardless, Wikipedia says [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29#General_definition) ***is used to hide the values or state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them***.

Answer (score 0):

No as OOP follows a strict hierarchy. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898909/is-it-possible-to-call-subclasses-methods-on-a-superclass-object),

> Think of it this way, all dogs are animals, but not all animals are
> dogs. All dogs bark, but not all animals bark.

You can not have a super class call a subclass method as the super class ***does not*** inherit anything from the subclass.