# Access a subclass method through an ArrayList

Tags: java, casting, subclass

I have an ArrayList of Players in a Game class. A player can play as a human or as a cpu. So I have the classes Human and CPU that extends the Player's class

```
public class Game{
    private ArrayList<Player> _list;
    Game(){
        _list=new ArrayList<Player>();
    }
    //**********
    void doSomething(){
        for(int i=0;i<_list.size();i++){
            Player q=_list.get(i);
            if(q is instaceof CPU) //I'd like to call a CPU method
            else //I'd like to call a Human method
        }

    }
}

public abstract class Player{
    private String name;

    Player(string name2){
        name=name;
   }
    //********** more methods

}

pulic class Human extends Player{
    public Human(String name){ 
        super(name);
    }
    void methodHuman();       
}

public class CPU extends Player{
    public CPU (String name){
        super(name);
    } 
    void methodCPU();
}
```

How I can call a method of a subclasses? I have to do a cast?

Comment: You're thinking about it the wrong way. The `Human` and `CPU` classes that extend `Player` should override a method in `Player`. Then you won't have to check if it's an instance of `Foo` you can just call the method.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do a cast. Depending on the nature of the method, polymorphism might be your friend. Define a method (say `methodDoThing`) in your Player, and then have a specific implementation in each subclass.

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898909/is-it-possible-to-call-subclasses-methods-on-a-superclass-object